# How best to Compare JSON object values to a fixed array in JScript

Tags: arrays, json, loops, for-loop, jscript

I would like to compare JSON values to an array of values but I d'ont know what's the best scenario to go with.

I got a JSON object with expected values (could have 1 value , 2 or more)
I have a DB function that returns a fix number of values, say 10 values all the time and I would like to know if my JSON values matches the right one coming from DB.
Ex:

My JSON var is :

```
 var expValues = {
            "id": "123",
            "age": 23
        };
```

My DB will push some values to an Array of objects.

Ex:

```
    if ((rs.BOF) && (rs.EOF))
    {
        //nothing found;
    }
    else
    {
        while (!rs.EOF)
        {
            aDetails.push(
            {
                "id": rs.fields("id").Value,
                "name": rs.fields("name").Value,
                "age": rs.fields("age").Value,
                "sex": rs.fields("sex").Value,
                "hobby": rs.fields("hobby").Value
            });
            rs.MoveNext();
        }
    }
     rs.close;
 //Close connection then return
 return aDetails;
```

basically I want to make sure values coming from JSON match the right ones coming from DB. (id for example).

Comment: Pls also put some ref example with full object details of `aDetails` as well

Comment: Are you trying to find out if they are completely equal? Or only values that are present in both sides?

Comment: Only expected values that are present in my JSON object. My aDetails array could have up to 50 values :) so kinda I would like to know if my JSON expected values match with the same coming from DB. (id, age always exist in both but need to compare the values)

Comment: @fazlook1 I have assumed some values for `aDetails` and added an answer. Pls check

Answer (score 4):

I have assumed `aDetails` to have something like below data.

```js
let aDetails = [{
  "id": "123",
   "name": "as",
   "age": 23,
   "sex": "m",
   "hobby": "abc"
}, {
  "id": "1234",
   "name": "as1",
   "age": 23,
   "sex": "m",
   "hobby": "abc"
}, {
  "id": "12",
   "name": "as2",
   "age": 23,
   "sex": "m",
   "hobby": "abc"
}]

var expValues = {
            "id": "123",
            "age": 23
        };
        
function isObjectMatched(obj) {
  return aDetails.some(d => Object.entries(obj).every(([k, v]) => d[k] == v))
}

console.log(isObjectMatched(expValues))
```

Comment: This code is amazing and works like a charm :)  but I am sad to say I need it in JScript & not JavaScript. Sorry :( I will update my question.

Comment: @fazlook1 I wish I could if I knew syntax of JScript but I don't

Comment: @fazlook1 As far as I can read online. JScript is more or less same and so you can try this code in JScript. If it works then great else you can evaluate what error is coming and start to resolve that.

Comment: Thank you :) I appreciate your help. All the syntax does not work in JScript :( I will try to make them JSON string , then split and compare but I might have a challenge where some strings may have comma in them as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is a general purpose way of indexing list of objects for fast retrieval with any configuration of properties.

```
// javascript version
function makeIndex (arrayOfObject, listOfPropertyToIndex) {
  var index = {};

  index.objToKey = function (o) {
    var key = [];
    listOfPropertyToIndex.forEach((p) => {
      key.push(""+o[p]);
    });
    return key.join("_");
  };

  arrayOfObject.forEach((o) => {
    index[objToKey(o)] = o;
  });

  index.match = function (object) {
    var key = index.objToKey(object);
    if (index.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return index[key];
    };
    return null;
  });

  return index;
}

// jscript version
function makeIndex (arrayOfObject, listOfPropertyToIndex) {
  var index = {};

  index.objToKey = function (o) {
    var key = [];
    for (var p in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        key.push(""+o[p]);
      }
    }
    return key.join("_");
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfObject.length; ++i) {
    index[objToKey(arrayOfObject[i])] = o;
  } 

  index.match = function (object) {
    var key = index.objToKey(object);
    if (index.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      return index[key];
    };
    return null;
  });

  return index;
}
```

Here is how to use it

```
var expValues = {
        "id": "123",
        "age": 23
    };

var index = makeIndex(aDetails, ["id","age"]);

var obj = index.match(expValues);
if (obj) {
   ... obj ...
}

var index_name = makeIndex(aDetails, ["name"]);

var person = {"name":"as2"};

var obj2 = index_name.match(person);
if (obj2) {
   ... obj2 ...
}
```

Comment: Will give it a try :) and get back to you

Comment: @fazlook1 This is for unique keys.  It possible to modify this to return an array of matches when multiple object produce the same index key.

Comment: Unfortunately, I changed my question to be in JScript & not in Java Script.

Comment: @fazlook1 I've added a jscript version.

Comment: Is there an online editor for JScript where I can test those stuff quickly ?

Comment: Something is not working....it is not going through function (o) , we cannot use for (var p in o) in Jscript

Comment: Where are you running the JScript?  This will influence what code to use to iterate through an object's properties.

Comment: Software called TestComplete for automation.